# Replaced a large wooden gate with double wooden gate, hinge side is level on both gates, but sides where meet sag in opposite directions

Tags: gates

Because we had a large 8' x 6' wooden privacy fence gate that warped and sagged to such a great degree, I took it down and built two smaller gates, (6 x 3') to replace it.  The original posts that the gate was attached to were extremely warped and twisted so I also built a frame attached but independent to the old post that is square and level, for the new gate.  I placed three- 3" hinges on each gate. My problem is on the side the hinges are on is level but the side where the gates are to meet are misaligned. No matter what I do the gate on the north post aligns to the west and the gate on the south post aligns to the east. I have checked and it is not warped wood nor are the frames not square.  The hinges are placed level and aligned properly. I have tried turning the frames around, making sure all my joints are square, everyting I can think of but no matter what I try where the two gates meet the one on the north angles west and the one on the south angles east. Think of it as the gates where they meet are making an X where they should be making an "I"

Comment: probably your gates are twisted,

Comment: It could be as simple as the gate on one side is higher than the gate on the other. If both gates have true posts it can be the hardware is not totally plumb. Both cases can cause issues, my plant owner had massive brick entrances with beautiful metal gates that won’t close properly but open fine, the gats are not hung plumb. They meet in the middle but that is it and 22 amps on the controller won’t bring them back , only 8” drop in the swing but think to think of pulling over 500 lbs it takes a bit of torque and these are pin and sleeve hinges. (High friction)